# CSS or Javascript percentage from another element without the bad effect of page being loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried to google and search the stack overflow for this particular question but without success.

The problem is that the element that I want to set its width based on another element is already loaded by the browser to its own width and then changed by the javascript (my current solution, and most solutions that I found) which produces that unwanted transition at load.

My question is there a way to set the width of an element with javascript before the el. is loaded or is there any other way with CSS and some variables or whatever?

CSS

```
#designsBar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 9rem;
    left: 12.5%;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
}
```

Javascript

```
window.onload = function(e){
  var widthN = document.getElementById('logoTxt').offsetWidth + document.getElementById('pagelogo').offsetWidth;

  document.getElementById('designsBar').style.width = widthN - 16 + "px";
};
```

Comment: It might make more sense to change how you build this layout to begin with … but advising on that would require that you describe to us what that layout actually is to begin with. If this is just about a couple of elements “in one row”, then you should probably switch from positioning stuff absolutely to using flexbox instead.

Comment: It's hard to say from your question but in addition to CBroe's comment you may want to look up `calc` in css... you can then do something like `width: calc(100% - 30px)` where 30px is your fixed width element

Answer (score 1):

If your `pageLogo` is a fixed width you can use `calc` in css:

```
#designsBar{
    width: calc(100% - "add whatever your pixel width of logo is here"px)
}
```

Or as CBroe said in the comments you can use `flex`